# Find all distinct pairs from Parent and Child collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core I have:

```
public class Runner {
  public List<String> Types { get; }
  public Target Target { get; }
}

public class Target {
  public List<String> Regions { get; }
}
```

I need to get all distinct combinations of `Type / Region` from a `List<Runner>`.

I used a `Select` and tried a `SelectMany` but I have not been able to flatten it:

```
var pairs = runners.Select(x => (x.Types, x.Target.Regions));
```

How to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data with enough rows and the result you want based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine each individual type with each individual region, it's something like this:

```
var pairs = runners
    .SelectMany(
        runner => runner.Types.SelectMany(
            type => runner.Target.Regions.Select(
                region => (type, region)
            )
        )
    )
    .Distinct();
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmpOpu) in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce all the `Type/Region` pairs by nesting a `.Select()` inside a nested `.SelectMany()`; e.g. as follows:

```csharp
List<(string Type, string Region)> pairs = runners
    .SelectMany(runner => runner.Types
        .SelectMany(type => runner.Target.Regions
            .Select(region => ( Type: type, Region: region ) )))
    .OrderBy(pair => pair.Type)
    .ThenBy(pair => pair.Region)
    .ToList();
```

(Ordering is optional, of course. :) )

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/epCIMd).